# Section in Header without number in unnumbered section

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm trying to get the section name without the number in the header using fancyheader. It works if I use a numebered section, but if I don't want the section number in the document (\section*{Section Name} ) the header disappears.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\uppercase{\markright{#1}}}

\rhead{\rightmark}
\lhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section*{First Section}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This gets explained in the user's manual of `fancyhdr` on page 11 (ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). Also note that it is advised to put the `\markboth`-command inside the `\section*{...}`.

Comment: I had the same problem and was woundering how exactly the `\markboth`-comand is used. This is why I'm writing this comment. It is explained on page 15 in the above mentioned document: `\section*{Sectionname\markboth{Sectionname}}` .

Answer (score 0):

Use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}`. It will register the name but not the number. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: If you're not careful, that will turn off section numbering for more than just the one section you're interested in.  It would probably be better to follow the advice of `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Likely. I hadn't thought of that.